# Instance of a non-compact and non-euclidean complex manifolds

Tags: reference-request, examples-counterexamples, complex-geometry

The only concrete example of complex manifolds neither compact nor euclidean are $\Bbb P^n(\Bbb C)\setminus K$ where $K\subset\Bbb P^n(\Bbb C)$ is compact, for $n\ge2$.

Are there other concrete examples?

Comment: What's your definition of Euclidean?

Comment: Subset of $\Bbb C^n$

Comment: $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})\setminus K$ can very well be Euclidean (take $K$ to be the complement of an affine chart, for example). I think the right hypothesis to get something non-Euclidean is to take $K$ to be a compact complex submanifold of dimension $\ge2$.

Comment: @Thorgott: thanks. You mean dimension or codimension? And what about $\Bbb P^2(\Bbb C)$ minus a point?

Comment: I mean codimension. A point in $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$ has codimension $2$, so that works. More generally, if $X$ is a compact, connected, complex manifold and $Y\subseteq X$ is a non-empty submanifold of codimension $\ge2$, $X\setminus Y$ is a non-compact and non-Euclidean complex manifold. Another class of examples are complex manifolds $X\times Y$ with $X,Y$ non-empty, $X$ non-Euclidean (e.g. $X$ compact and not a point) and $Y$ non-compact (the point being that if a non-empty product is compact/Euclidean, so is each factor).

Comment: Thanks! That's an answer, I would copy it as such!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two classes of examples:

1. Let $X$ be a non-empty, non-Euclidean complex manifold and $Y$ a non-empty, non-compact complex manifold. Then, $X\times Y$ is a complex manifold, which is non-compact (since $Y$ is a continuous image of $X\times Y$ and non-compact) and non-Euclidean (since $X$ is non-Euclidean and a complex submanifold of $X\times Y$).
2. Let $X$ be a non-empty, compact, complex manifold and $Y\subseteq X$ be a non-empty, closed, complex submanifold of codimension $\ge2$. Then, $X\setminus Y$ is an open subset of $X$, hence a complex manifold. If $X\setminus Y$ were compact, it would be closed in $X$, since $X$ is hausdorff, so $Y$ would then be open in $X$, contradicting that $Y$ has positive codimension. Thus, $X\setminus Y$ is non-compact. Furthermore, $\dim(X\setminus Y)=\dim(X)=\dim(Y)+2\ge2$, so $X\setminus Y$ contains two distinct points. If $X\setminus Y$ embedded in some $\mathbb{C}^n$, there would be a holomorphic function $\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ separating the images of these two points (e.g. a linear function would do). However, pulling this back along the embedding would yield a non-constant holomorphic function on $X\setminus Y$. Since $Y$ has codimension $\ge2$, this extends to a holomorphic function on $X$ by a Hartogs's theorem, which is constant by Liouville's theorem, contradiction. Thus, $X\setminus Y$ is non-Euclidean.

Comment: 3. if $f\colon X\setminus Y\hookrightarrow\Bbb C^n$ is the holomorphic embedding and $\phi\colon\Bbb C^n\to\Bbb C$ is the holomorphic mapping separating the image of $z,w\in\Bbb C^n$, corresponding to $p,q\in X\setminus Y$, you consider $\phi\circ f\colon X\setminus Y\to\Bbb C$, which is holomorphic and extends to the whole $X$, which is compact, hence $\phi\circ f$ is constant, so it doesn't separate $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I have some questions: 1) do you mean $\dim(X\setminus Y)=\dim X-\dim Y\ge2$, correct? 2) I don't see how do you contradict the connectedness of $X$. I would say that if $X\setminus Y$ is compact, then it is closed in $X$ so $Y$ is open; but $Y$ is open by hypothesis, so it should be either $\emptyset$ or $X$, and both are false.

Comment: So it doesn't seem we need to assume $X$ connected; am I wrong?

Comment: Moreover the complement of a complex submanifold of codimension $\ge1$ is connected, so it sounds strange

Comment: 1) No, I mean $\dim(X\setminus Y)=\dim(X)$, since $X\setminus Y$ is an open subset of $X$. 2) I argue $X\setminus Y$ is both open and closed in $X$, yet neither equal to $\emptyset$ or $X$, which contradicts connectedness. I don't see how what you wrote circumvents connectedness. Actually, though, connectedness *is* unnecessary, I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: I was wrong with connectedness. But please, look at 2.
Can't we argue that $Y$ is open in that way?

Comment: Yes. My edit was too roundabout, hopefully the argument is concise now.